# python subtract dicts with mismatched keys

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I have two lines (x, y) stored as dicts:

```py
# DICT = { time : voltage }
line1 = { 1.2 : 500, 1.4 : 600, 1.6 : 700}
line2 = { 1.3 : 550, 1.5 : 650, 1.7 : 750}
```

I want to observe the differences between the lines, but when I simply plot:

```py
plt.plot(line1.keys(), line1.values())
plt.plot(line2.keys(), line2.values())
plt.show()
```

The scale is such that the minute differences between the lines are not visible. I would like to **subtract** the lines from one another to create a 3rd line that represents those differences. If the keys matched up perfectly I could do something like:

```py
line3={}
for k in line1.keys():
    line3[k] = line1[k] - line2[k]
```

Unfortunately the keys (x-values) are not the same in both dicts. How should I go about subtracting these two lines from each other?

Comment: If you are using python3.7+ then dict keys keep their insertion order, which could help with what you want?.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have x1, y1 and x2, y2.
In order to perform meaningful subtraction you will have to have common x.
The practice is to resample one of the signals according to the others x.

numpy.interp can do it.
For example

```
new_y2 = np.interp(x1, x2, y2)
d = new_y2 - y1 # both over x1
```

Comment: I'm new to `np.interp()`, but based on my understanding of what's going on in this thread, I believe it would be more meaningful to rename `new_y2` as `new_y1`, as these are probably the interpolation-based values of `y`, for the values of `x` that are in `x1`. Or have I got it all wrong about this thread?

Comment: No. We are resampling y2 on x1. Please take a look https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Answer (score 1):

For me this sounds like you have data with different sample rate / time stamps.

Depending on the data you have, you could try to use their relative timestamp from the first element - if they have same sample rate:

```py
#with 1.2, 1.3 == value of your first timestamp
d1_rel = {key - 1.2: value for key, value in d1.items()}
d2_rel = {key - 1.3: value for key, value in d2.items()}
```

otherwise if your data has a different sample rate:

The "pandas" library might be your friend.
Have a look at the resample method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample